# How to get text from span ID

Tags: jquery

Under JQM, how can i get the text inside SPANs?

As i searched, there are hundreds of method to do that. 
But nothing available on my case.

I want display those SPAN value as 123 - 456 on section  "mainPage".

```
<script>
$('a[name=submit_button]').click(function(){
 var Val1 = $('#zip1').text(text);
 var Val2 = $('#zip2').text(text);

 ...
</script>

<section id="mainPage" data-role="page">
 ...
</section>

<section id="zipSearch" data-role="dialog" data-theme="d">
 ...
 <ul><li><a name="sumit_button href="#mainPage"><span id="zip1">123</span><span id="zip2">456</span></li>
 </ul>
 ...
 </section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use

```
var Val1 = $("#zip1").text();
var Val2 = $("#zip2").text();
```

It probably doesn't work for you because you have syntax error in your a tag (forgot one of "). Change it to:

```
<a name="sumit_button" href="#mainPage">
```

**EDIT**: I have also just noticed you haven't closed your a tag either. Clear up your HTML tags, spooky things happen when you your strings or tags aren't terminated in the right place :)

Comment: Oh it's syntext error. ^^ Anyway how can i check if the $("#zip1").text(); bring up right value?

Comment: Inside your button function: alert($("#zip1").text()); This will show an alert box with the value of $("#zip1").text(); Alternatively use firebug or other development tool like that to see the value.

Comment: Here is my working source code. http://jsfiddle.net/8C88b/ if Click the first row of span id succefully bring up value and input to <input ..> but after that can't bring up values.

Comment: @paulycho: Three things in your code: (1) In function live use attr instead of data. (2) in function click you need to look for children of a-element that has been clicked. (3) You have duplicate id-tags on one page. If you want your page to meet the standards do not use duplicate id values on the page. Consider using class instead. I have amended your code: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/BKNAv/) works fine for me, let me know if you're having any problems.

Comment: Great Thaks for your advice. Your source magically work fine on my mobile phone. But the real script is bit more complicate. After adapt your code to my original script. It won't work. I think because of dynamic object (created by Ajax Post) for the list of search result. I uploads the original to jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nxCvW/ . Great Thanks again. I searched solution all the week.

Answer (score 3):

I think you just want

```
var Val1 = $('#zip1').text();
var Val2 = $('#zip2').text();
```